# Regex expression or another way to split sentence

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a sentence like this.

```
Crit Hit Chance 0,3 Armor 200
```

or just

```
Damage hit 0,2
```

and I need to Split the sentence so I can get the Name and the Value into a object that is going into my database. I can´t split at " " because some of the names contains space and I can split at `.` or `,` because the value contains that.

Is there someone out there, who can help me split the sentence like I want. I don't understand regEx that well, but I think that is the easiest way?

The output should be **Name:** Critical hit damage **Value:** 0,3

possible inputs:Critical hit damage 0,3 Armor 200

I want output

Critical hit Damage

0,3

Armor

200

**possible input:** Critical hit damage 0,3

**output**

Critical hit damage

0,3

**possible input:** Armor 200

**Output:**

Armor

200

**possilble input:** Preformance MainStat

**Output:**

Preformance

MainStat

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: I want the text to be saved as name in my database and value as value.

Comment: We don't know what name and value should be, only you know that. Please provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: Namely, it is unclear what the output for the `Crit Hit Chance 0,3 Armor 200` string is. Are you trying to get anything before a number and then a number? Try [`(.*?)\s*(\d*[.,]?\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.*%3f%29%5cs*%28%5cd*%5b.%2c%5d%3f%5cd%2b%29&i=Crit+Hit+Chance+0%2c3+Armor+200)

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: You should set up an exhaustive list of possible inputs along with the expected outputs, only then can anyone give you more concrete advice. You can easily get opinions about possible regexps or similar that may or may not help you but I don't see that as a constructive and helpful answer, other than to spark a discussion.

Comment: For instance, you've given two example texts and then shown what you want, "**Name**: Critical hit damage **Value**: 0,3". But where did "Critical hit damage" come from? It's not part of the first two texts. You have "Critical hit *chance*", and "Damage hit" (missing Critical). Without a clear question then nobody can give you a clear answer.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Well the text is text and the numbers is numbers, always. So i´m sorry if I was unclear but I think I got an answer that work from Joshua Webb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the name can never contain digits, presumably you want something like:

```cs
Match result;
result = Regex.Match(input, @"(\D+)\s+(\d+(,\d+)?)\s*");
while (result.Success)
{
    var name = result.Groups[1];
    var value = result.Groups[2];
    result = result.NextMatch();
}
```

The expression groups together a string of characters that cannot contain digits `(\D+)` followed by some amount of white space `\s+`, then some digits `\d+`, then possibly a comma with more digits, or nothing `(,\d+)?`, finally consuming any trailing whitespace between the next chunk of text in the sentence `\s*`

Note that the first group (group 0) is the entire string of text that matched the whole expression, so the first capture group is group 1.

Comment: Yeah, it might suffice. A tip: `[^\d]` = `\D`

Comment: hah, why do I always forget about the negative character class shorthands?!

Comment: Your last example in your edit looks like this won't totally work... your input seems to not lend itself to this kind of parsing. There doesn't seem to be any sort of unifying pattern

Comment: Well the last example is another method so perhaps it´s another way to do that one?

Comment: @JoshuaWebb You solved my problem. I´m sorry I can give you a point but I don´t have the reputation yet. Thank you so much.